# How do i get the gaps coloured Tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

There are gaps around the labels [image]

How do I fix this? Yes, I realize my code is very messy.

```py
ttk.Label(frm, text="Monday:                ",background = '#408EC6',borderwidth=5,border=5).grid(column=0, row=0)
ttk.Label(frm, text="Tuesday:                ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=1, row=0)
ttk.Label(frm, text="Wednesday:                ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=2, row=0)
ttk.Label(frm, text="Thursday:                ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=3, row=0)
ttk.Label(frm, text="Friday:                ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=4, row=0)
ttk.Label(frm, text="Saturday:                ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=5, row=0)
ttk.Label(frm, text="Sunday:                ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=6, row=0)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Quit", command=weekList.destroy).grid(column=7, row=0)
ttk.Label(frm, text="             ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=0, row=3)
ttk.Label(frm, text="             ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=0, row=4)
ttk.Label(frm, text="             ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=0, row=5)
ttk.Label(frm, text="             ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=0, row=6)
ttk.Label(frm, text="             ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=0, row=7)
ttk.Label(frm, text="             ",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=0, row=8)

ttk.Checkbutton(frm, text="", var=mondayChange).grid(column=0, row=12)
ttk.Checkbutton(frm, text="", var=tuesdayChange).grid(column=1, row=12)
ttk.Checkbutton(frm, text="", var=wednesdayChange).grid(column=2, row=12)
ttk.Checkbutton(frm, text="", var=thursdayChange).grid(column=3, row=12)
ttk.Checkbutton(frm, text="", var=fridayChange).grid(column=4, row=12)
ttk.Checkbutton(frm, text="", var=saturdayChange).grid(column=5, row=12)
ttk.Checkbutton(frm, text="", var=sundayChange).grid(column=6, row=12)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Change\nSelected\n   days", command=lambda:changeMeal(week)).grid(column=7, row=1)

ttk.Label(frm,text="Name of the meal:").grid(column=8,row=0)
ttk.Entry(frm,width=15,textvariable = mealName).grid(column=8,row=1)
ttk.Label(frm,text="How many\ningredients?").grid(column=8,row=2)
ttk.Spinbox(frm, from_=1, to=20,width=4,textvariable=spinValue).grid(column=8,row=3)
ttk.Button(frm, text="Add a meal", command=lambda:makeMeal(spinValue.get(),mealName.get())).grid(column=8,row=4)
```

I tried using the background function in the label but that still leaves gaps.
Each one of the lines is a separate label except the name of the meal which is 2 lines.

```py
ttk.Label(frm, text="\n Ingredients:",background = '#408EC6').grid(column=I, row=2)
```

Comment: Did you try changing background color of mainwindow which is Tk instance?

Comment: Do you want the items in each list of ingredients to look like they are in the same blue rectangle? Gaps between labels in the same list? Or gaps between lists?